# Write a loop through a pandas DataFrame, extract the value (a url link), and then pass each url link element through a function

Tags: python, python-newspaper

I am interested in running article.text() from the Python Library Newspaper over a number of links (n) that I currently have stored in a (nx1) dataframe (let's call this dataframe df). I would then like to store the results in another column of df.

Here is the code that I currently have written:

Function:

```
def newspaper_analysis(row):
    url = row
    article = Article(url)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    text = article.text
    return text
```

Applying it to the dataframe:

```
df['text'] = df.apply(newspaper_analysis)
```

I think that the problem lies within the line "url = row," but I am not sure. If you could advise on how to write a loop through a pandas DataFrame, extract the value from it (a url link), and then pass that link through the newspaper_analysis function I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your column name in dataframe is 'ArticleUrl'. Then use -

```
df['text'] = df['ArticleUrl'].apply(newspaper_analysis)
```